# PHP: Match the final parethesized word in a string?

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = 'Foo (Bar) (Baz)'
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $string, $match);
```

In the above PHP, $match is returned as

```
array ( 0 => '(Bar)', 1 => 'Bar', )
```

Is it possible to alter the regex so it returns:

```
array ( 0 => '(Baz)', 1 => 'Baz', )
```

.i.e. the final word in parenthesis.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` and grab the last element in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#.*\((.*?)\)#
```

try this.this should do it.

or

```
#\((.*?)\)(?!.*\()#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex which uses lookaheads and behinds to make it more clear

```
/(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\($)/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
\(((?!.*\().*?)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UKcZl6ST9NehKjWl)